# Can you have a function in an inline powershell script in a Azure pipeline YAML file?

Tags: function, powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, hoisting

I want to be able to simplify some inline powerscript in an AzureCLI task using a function, similar to the following:

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "My Task"
    inputs:
      scriptType: pscore
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        Do-Something "hello" "world"
        Do-Something "goodbye" "world"

        function Do-Something { 
          Param
          (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
            [string] $Hello,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
            [string] $World
          )

          Write-Host "$Hello $World"
        }
```

However this fails with the following error:

```
+ Do-Something "hello" "world"
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Do-Something:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
```

Is this possible?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define the function (iow. execute the statement that starts with the `function` keyword) before you can call it. Move the `Do-Something ...` statements below the function definition and it'll work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) provided the crucial pointer:

The use of Azure is *incidental* to your problem, which stems from a **fundamental PowerShell behavior**:

- Unlike other languages, PowerShell performs ***no* function hoisting**, ...
- ... which means that **you must declare your functions *before* you can call them**, i.e., in your source code you must place the function definition *before* any statements that call it.

The relevant conceptual help topic, [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions), historically didn't make that clear, unfortunately, but this has since been corrected. Offline help of existing PowerShell installations would need to be updated manually to see the change.

---

To spell the solution out for your code:

```
 - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "My Task"
    inputs:
      scriptType: pscore
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        # First, declare the function.
        function Do-Something { 
          Param
          (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
            [string] $Hello,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
            [string] $World
          )

          Write-Host "$Hello $World"
        }

        # Now you can call it.
        Do-Something "hello" "world"
        Do-Something "goodbye" "world"
```